# How do I navigate to the top level component from an ancestor?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My app structure looks like this

```
SwitchNavigator
    Login
    StackNavigator
        DrawerNavigator
            TabNavigator
                Home
                Profile
                Resources
            Settings
            About
            Log Out Button
```

In the drawer navigator, I have a button to log out, which I would like to send you back to the Initial SwitchNavigator.  I can navigate to the login page, but the header I have in the StackNavigator shows, the back button takes you back into the app, logging back in shows the Home screen with no TabNavigator.

Happy to provide additional information or code, not sure what will be needed to help me with this problem.  Thanks for taking a look!

This is what the log out button currently does:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(item.screenToNavigate);
```

Comment: if you can share code on expo snack, it will be easier to help you.